# Radiometric calibration NDVI values in Excel

Tags: qgis, excel, ndvi

I´m doing NDVI analysis, but i forgot to do Radiometric calibrations in QGIS. So the NDVI values in my excel table are in DNs. Can I do this calibration directly in excel?

Comment: You'll have to provide much more data and context to get a reliable answer. For example, what sensor are you working with? Are you talking about altering the NDVI values after the fact?

Comment: I´m using three Landsats: Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS, Landsat 7 ETM+ and Landsat 5 TM. I´m analysing the productivity of pastures from different years by creating NDVI images. From what i have been reading, i had to do a radiometric calibration, converting DNs to radiance. Seeing that at that time I didn´t know this, i need to do that radiometric calibration on all the NDVI values i have in a excel table.

Comment: There are a few things here that don't track. First , you cannot correct NDVI, you correct the bands that comprise the metric before deriving the metric. Second, NDVI is a ratio and values should be floating point ranging -1 to 1. Some software scales to 8-bit this, returning a 0-255 integer. Be sure of the methods how are using and what the results are.